# Jquery validation not taking numbers as input name

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this validation code

```
<input id="00N6F00000HqdQP" name="00N6F00000HqdQP" type="text" />

$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
      00N6F00000HqdQP: "required",
    },
    messages: {
      00N6F00000HqdQc: "Required field",
    },
    
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

the problem is, Jquery is not validating with the input name "00N6F00000HqdQP". It works fine with either number or alphabets. But not mixed.

Comment: Have you tried this `"00N6F00000HqdQP": "required",`

Comment: validate() is not a jquery function or method, please specify what are you using. Although it looks like you just need to put the name between quotes in the rules and messages parameters.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you very much. That worked